# Solving permutation problem sequentially.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have four dice and we want to know the number of ways in which at lease one dice shows 3.
This is pretty simple if we judge it directly by saying that the number of ways in which all the dice can show any number is $6^4$ and the number of ways in which $3$ does not appear anywhere is $5^4$. Subtracting the two gives us the right answer i.e $679$.

I am new to combinatorics and hence when I tried to solve it sequentially by writing out things like the number of ways through permutation formula in which we count the number of ways one by one, first assuming that we have only one $3$, then two $3s$ and so on, I get confused a lot.

Can anybody help me with the procedure of solving this by writing permutation formula for each and every sequence (one three at a time, two threes at a time etc.) That would be of great help since I can find no other way through which I can remove my doubts.

Comment: Everybody gets confused with counting arguments.  To do exactly $1$ three, note that there are $4$ places the three might occur and that the others have to be non-threes, so $4\times 5^3$.  And so on.

Comment: Can you please do it for the second step. Since I faced the biggest problem when  two $3s$ were there.

Comment: @lulu Can you follow the same approach you did for the first case rather than pursuing the combination formula approach?

Comment: For two threes, you first need to place them.  There are $\binom 42$ ways to do that (by definition).  The other two slots have to be filled by non-threes so $\binom 42 \times 5^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways to get exactly $k$ threes when rolling $n$ dice is:

$$\binom{n}{k}\cdot5^{n-k}$$

---

For $4$ dice, we have:

- The number of ways to get exactly $\color\red0$ threes: $\binom{4}{\color\red0}\cdot5^{4-\color\red0}=625$
- The number of ways to get exactly $\color\red1$ threes: $\binom{4}{\color\red1}\cdot5^{4-\color\red1}=500$
- The number of ways to get exactly $\color\red2$ threes: $\binom{4}{\color\red2}\cdot5^{4-\color\red2}=150$
- The number of ways to get exactly $\color\red3$ threes: $\binom{4}{\color\red3}\cdot5^{4-\color\red3}=20$
- The number of ways to get exactly $\color\red4$ threes: $\binom{4}{\color\red4}\cdot5^{4-\color\red4}=1$

In order to verify this: $625+500+150+20+1=1296=6^4$.

Comment: Sir, can we anyhow solve the problem by just using permutation formula. If there is, can you give any hints to me regarding the line of thought that I need to develop to get through the problem?

Comment: @HarshSharma: What do you mean by "permutation formula", and what's wrong with using the formula that I have noted at the top of this answer?

Comment: There is nothing wrong and I truly appreciate your answer but since I am currently studying permutation, I just wanted to know how could this be solved through permutation.

Comment: @HarshSharma: I meant to ask what's wrong with it in terms of *permutation* (i.e., what exactly do you mean by "permutation formula" which is not present in the formula that I have given you)?

Answer (score 2):

barak manos' answer is perfectly fine, but since you keep on harping about permutations, firstly note that there is only one way a $3$ can occur on a throw, whereas there are $5$ ways a non-3, let's call it **N**, can occur on a throw.

So you can formulate it as [Ways for a **pattern** to occur on a throw]$\times$ [its **permutations**]

Single $3,\;e.g.\;\; N-3-N-N:\;\; (1\cdot5^3) \times \dfrac{4!}{1!3!}$

Double $3, \;e.g.\;\; N-3-3-N:\;\; (1^2\cdot5^2) \times \dfrac{4!}{2!2!}$

Triple $3, \;e.g.\;\; 3-N-3-3:\;\; (1^3\cdot5^1) \times \dfrac{4!}{3!1!}$

All four $3, \;e.g.\;\; 3-3-3-3:\;\; (1^4) \times \dfrac{4!}{4!}$

Answer (score 1):

Number of ways = 1 time 3 + 2 time 3 + 3 time 3 + 4 time 3

Number of ways = C(4,1) * $(5)^3$ + C(4,2) * $(5)^2$ + C(4,3) * $(5)^1 + C(4,4) * (5)^0$